# Python cx_Oracle XMLTYPE data retrieval error DPI-1040: LOB was already closed

Tags: python, oracle, xml-parsing, cx-oracle

Clob issues, with cx_oracle version 6 is not working with python3.6 cx_oracle version 8.

```
xml_string = record['T.XML_COLUMN.getCLOBVal()'].read()
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1040: LOB was already closed
```

Edit: just downgraded the version and it’s working again. Thanks!

Comment: Please help us!  Give us more details.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Note that if the data is going to be less than 1GB, it will be a lot faster to read it as a string.  This will probably also fix the LOB error you have.  See the cx_Oracle documentation [Fetching LOBs as Strings and Bytes](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/lob_data.html#fetching-lobs-as-strings-and-bytes) and the example [ReturnLobsAsStrings.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to set debugging flags from

https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tracing_sql.html

and check if there are Oracle Error messages written ?

Anyway - since you have changed Python release and cx_Oracle release and I have found

https://github.com/oracle/odpi/commit/0eea11463814a7eeaaef2c23cc1058c3353069fb

it could be

- a flaw in cx_Oracle 8.0 (-> Try to test with 7.0 if this is Python 3.x compatible,
- an issue of the Database (-> try to connect to previous DB like 12.1 etc)#
- an issue of Client (-> try different Clients)
- or an issue in ODPI itself (Since error is DPI this looks to be a hint) and so testing with older clients should be done first

If nothing works, try to open service request at Oracle Support

Comment: If nothing else works, open an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues) since cx_Oracle is open source and not something Oracle Support look after.

Answer (score 0):

Check your query statement，if you usesd WM_Concat function, converts it to varchar type or other.
Because the result of wm_concat function is LOB type,and cx_oracle will throw the exception,"DPI-1040: LOB was already closed"